# How do I make a new branch without changes from my last branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Basically, I made branch1 off of master and made changes to the code there. Then I committed branch1 and pushed to remote. Now *I want to make branch2 off of master, but without the changes from branch1*. The problem is, when I make the new branch the code changes are still there locally on my computer. Thanks.

Comment: You're missing some information here. When you commit to a branch and then change to another branch the changes don't stay. Unless those changes were not committed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this happens to you, ensure the file you are seeing persistent local changes in is tracked by Git. That was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout master` then `git branch branch2`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why would that happen unless `branch1` is merged to `master` or you messed up something locally.

If you follow these steps, you shouldn't see a problem

```
git checkout master
git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master
git checkout -b branch1
git add .
git commit -m "Commit"
git push origin branch1

git checkout master
git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master
git checkout -b branch2
```

Comment: I didn't do the fetch and reset, is this something you have to do every time you do this?

Comment: Not really - but if there are changes merged to master, you want them to be on your branch, essentially it's a `git pull`